# RxSwift Subscriber receiving multiple events

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Consider the below code.

1. On tapButton, we subscribe to an Observable `isFetched` and then call `fetchPopularMovies()`.
2. `fetchPopularMovies()` in turn calls an API. When the response is received, we will send `OnNext(true)` event.

Problem is, I receive multiple events on 2nd button tap onwards. If I add onCompleted(), I don't even receive events on 2nd button tap onwards. My expectation is that one event will be triggered on each button tap. What am I missing here?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let popularMoviesURL = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=API_KEY")
    var isFetched = BehaviorSubject<Bool?>(value:nil)
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let observable = isFetched.asObservable()
        observable.subscribe(onNext: { observer in
            guard let result = observer else { return }
            print(result)
            print("onNext Recieved")
            
        }, onError: { _ in
            print("onError Recieved")
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        fetchPopularMovies()
    }
    
    func fetchPopularMovies() {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: popularMoviesURL!) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let _ = data else { return }
            self.isFetched.onNext(true)
           //self.isFetched.onCompleted()
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you subscribe every time on button tap

Comment: subscription is like news paper, once you subscribed it you will get all future releases of that news paper. if you subscribed two or five time to that news paper, you will get tow or five copy of that news paper.

Comment: in your case distinctuntilchanged

Comment: @SPatel thanks. I like the newspaper analogy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reactive code is declarative. It's "setup" code. So it should be placed where the comment says "Do any additional setup after loading the view."

The simplest change you can do to fix the problem you are having is to move the subscription into the `viewDidLoad` method as Satish Patel referenced in his comment.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    isFetched.subscribe(onNext: { observer in
        guard let result = observer else { return }
        print(result)
        print("onNext Recieved")

    }, onError: { _ in
        print("onError Recieved")
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

@IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: Any) {
    fetchPopularMovies()
}
```

(Note that `Subject`s should always be held with `let`s never `var`s.)

If you use RxCocoa, you can simplify this code even more:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let button = UIButton()
    let isFetched = BehaviorSubject<Bool?>(value:nil)
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let popularMoviesURL = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=API_KEY")!

        let fetchedData = button.rx.tap
            .flatMapLatest {
                URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: URLRequest(url: popularMoviesURL))
                    .catch { error in
                        print("onError Recieved")
                        return Observable.empty()
                    }
            }

        fetchedData
            .map { _ in true }
            .bind(to: isFetched)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Now, all of your code is "setup code" so it all goes in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks. Moved to viewDidLoad() and it works as expected. Let me try RxCocoa.